# UIActionSheet height on iPad

Tags: ipad

I have some troubles with UIActionsheet on iPad actionally
his height is not moving wherever the changes are, so I can't see the `Done` button

and here is my code :

```
-(void) showActionSheet{

UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:@"Done"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];

Reports = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //Add the picker
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 0, 0)];
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 20, 400, 420)];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[menu addSubview:datePicker];
[menu showFromRect:[self frame] inView:self animated:YES];        
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    [menu setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,480, 260)];
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    [menu setBounds:CGRectMake(-20,10,480, 400)];
menu.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
[menu release];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To see `Done` Button you can do one thing as I do always

```
UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
                                              delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:@""
                                     otherButtonTitles:@"",@"",@"Done",nil,nil];
```

I think this will work.

I know this is not a good way but you can do this for now.

Comment: another way is                                        UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"\n\n\n" 
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:@"Done"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];